# Logging solutions for cloudflare?

Tags: cloudflare

What log analysis and alerting systems are you using with Cloudflare, preferably PRO, not Enterprise, since Clouflare only retains 4 hours worth of Access log data?

I am thinking along the lines of Loggly, Splunk, Sumologic etc. I cannot seem to find anything that would work more or less out of the box ie some form of integration.

I am aware of Cloudflare's work with Google on their Enterprise plan.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you not have access to logs directly on the server?

Comment: I now realise that CF PRO is limited to Aggregate reporting. Enterprise has an API to share this data however. for ELK. Yes I do have access logs on the Azure App Service, and this is my current direction, and we do this manually ie downloading log files, but we would prefer a more automated approach.